# how to get Information of camera android

Tags: android, parameters, get

how i can get information of Camera android like list of parameters:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzINL.png)

please help.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to have the camera instance. This can be done by opening the camera:

```
Camera camera = Camera.open();
```

From there you can get the parameters by calling the `getParameters()` method on the `camera` instance.

Comment: android studio show:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
i don't no where i misstake

Answer (score 0):

```
Camera mcamera = Camera.open();
Camera.Parameters p= mCamera.getParameters();

String flashMode = p.getFlashMode();
```

Like this, you can get all the parameters you need.

Comment: i do like that but android studio show:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service

Comment: Give Permission in Manifiest.xml for Camera and so on